# How operations are performed for dynamic array?

Tags: c++, arrays, data-structures, stl, operations

I have studied everywhere in books about Dymanic arrays. I have used them in STL of C++.
But I am still unclear about what are Dynamic arrays. How the operations over Dynamic arrays are implemented.

Comment: read this: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++ there are (well, pretty soon will be!) 4 kinds of arrays: C-style static arrays, C++11 [static arrays](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array), C++ [dynamic vectors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and C++14 [dynamic arrays](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/dynarray/dynarray).

The C-style and C++11 static arrays take a compile-time constant size parameter and cannot be enlarged / shrunk after their initialization. C++ dynamic vectors can take any runtime number of elements at initialization, and can be enlarged / shrunk afterwards. With the upcoming C++14 Standard, there will also be `std::dynarray` that fills a smal gap between the existing containers: it will take a runtime number of elements during initialization, but cannot be enlarged / shrunk afterwards.

Here are some basic use cases:

```
static const int N = 4;                // compile-time constant int
int M = 4;                             // run-time int

int c[N] = { 0, 1, 2, 3 };             // C-style static array: compile-time constant size
std::array<int, N> a = { 0, 1, 2, 3 }; // C++11 static array: compile-time constant size

int rc[M] = { 0, 1, 2, 3 };             // ERROR: M is not a compile-time constant expression
std::array<int, M> ra = { 0, 1, 2, 3 }; // ERROR: M is not a compile-time constant expression

std::vector<int> v { std::begin(a), std::end(a) };   // C++ dynamic vector: runtime size, but can be enlarged afterwards
v.push_back(4);                                      // v enlarged to { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 } now
v.pop_back();                                        // v shrunk back to { 0, 1, 2, 3 }

std::dynarray<int> d { std::begin(v), std::end(v) }; // C++14 dynamic array: runtime size, but cannot be enlarged afterwards
```

Static arrays (C-style arrays, `std::array`) do static memory allocation on the stack. Dynamic arrays (`std::vector<T>` and `std::dynarray<T>`) can take an [Allocator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Allocator) template parameter. For `std::vector` this Allocator defaults to [`std::allocator<T>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator), which does dynamic low-level memory management behind the scenes using [`new`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new). For `std::dynarray` the memory is allocated from an unspecified source, which may, or may not, invoke the global `operator new`.

By supplying a user-defined allocator, both `std::vector` and `std::dynarray` can be made to work with stack-based memory allocation, e.g. using @HowardHinnant 's [stack allocator](http://home.roadrunner.com/~hinnant/stack_alloc.html).